# How can I integrate casperJS to Meteor's Velocity Test Runner?

Tags: meteor, casperjs, meteor-velocity

I have a bunch of ´casperJS´ tests which I would like to integrate to Velocity (currently I've written a small test runner which boots the meteor app with a different DB).

I've seen that [selenium-nightwatch](https://github.com/awatson1978/selenium-nightwatch/) has a file named ´velocity-integration.js´, so I will take a look at that file to see how can I integrate casper, but first I would like to hear suggestions/guidelines if there's any.

Is this integration possible right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this?

https://github.com/blazer82/meteor-casperjs/

It does what you're wanting to do :)

Comment: Thanks! It seems it needs Meteor 9.4+, I couldn't install it on 0.9.3.1 due to some coffescript dependency. I just gave it a quick try and my 2 casperjs tests fails on Velocity (they run fine on manual casperjs run). Also it seems that my mocha tests stopped from being runned, but this might be something else. I will check further later. In any case, this is the project I was looking for.

Comment: It's not working for me either on Meteor 1.0.: `Method not found [404] [...] resetReports`

Comment: Looks like the framework needs to be updated. We changed the API in velocity and resetReports is now velocity/reset/reports. You'll need to file a bug with blazer82